# how to add custom logic before sending DTO to client side?

Tags: java, dto, mapstruct

Probably this might be a very simple question but I am quite lost while solving the given problem.

I've an entity called MediaResource and it has id, imageName etc. fields, on the other hand, there is MediaResourceDTO it has imageName, byte[] resourceFile etc.

The idea is fetching the image name from database and before sending  MediaResourceDTO to client side, I want to load image file into MediaResourceDTO.

I don't know how to achieve this from MapStruct.

I've seen a couple of example of @Before and @After but I don't understand its use case.

Here is my source codes:
**MediaResourceMapper**

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring", uses = {VehicleMapper.class, })
public interface MediaResourceMapper {

    MediaResourceDTO mediaResourceToMediaResourceDTO(MediaResource mediaResource);

    List<MediaResourceDTO> mediaResourcesToMediaResourceDTOs(List<MediaResource> mediaResources);

    MediaResource mediaResourceDTOToMediaResource(MediaResourceDTO mediaResourceDTO);

    List<MediaResource> mediaResourceDTOsToMediaResources(List<MediaResourceDTO> mediaResourceDTOs);

    default MediaResource mediaResourceFromId(Long id) {
        if (id == null) {
            return null;
        }
        MediaResource mediaResource = new MediaResource();
        mediaResource.setId(id);
        return mediaResource;
    }
}
```

**MediaResource** Entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "media_resource")
public class MediaResource implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "field_name")
    private String fieldName;

    @Column(name = "original_media_file_name")
    private String originalMediaFileName;

    @Column(name = "encrypted_media_file_name")
    private String encryptedMediaFileName;


    @Column(name = "resource_file_content_type", nullable = false)
    private String resourceFileContentType;

}
```

**MediaResourceDTO**

```
public class MediaResourceDTO implements Serializable {

    private Long id;

    private String fieldName;

    private String originalMediaFileName;

    private String encryptedMediaFileName;

    @NotNull
    @Size(max = 20000000)
    @Lob
    private byte[] resourceFile;
    private String resourceFileContentType;

//Some getter and setters


    }
```

Thank you.

Comment: You can [customize your mapping](http://mapstruct.org/documentation/dev/reference/html/#_customizing_mappings). Show your mapper declaration so we can propose a solution.

Comment: thanks @JimmyB I've updated the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [customize your mappings](http://mapstruct.org/documentation/dev/reference/html/#_customizing_mappings) by providing a decorator. For this, you create your own class which implements your mapper's interface and overrides the desired mapping methods:

```
public abstract class MediaResourceMapperDecorator implements MediaResourceMapper {

    private final MediaResourceMapper delegate;

    public MediaResourceMapperDecorator(MediaResourceMapper delegate) {
        this.delegate = delegate;
    }

    @Override
    MediaResourceDTO mediaResourceToMediaResourceDTO(MediaResource mediaResource) {
        // Let MapStruct do the basic mapping:
        final MediaResourceDTO dto = this.delegate.mediaResourceToMediaResourceDTO( mediaResource );

        // Then load and add the file to the DTO:
        dto.setResourceFile( loadMyFile( mediaResource.getOriginalMediaFileName() );

        return dto;
    }
}
```

Then you use the `@DecoratedWith` annotation on the mapper to refer to your decorator:

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring", uses = {VehicleMapper.class, })
@DecoratedWith(MediaResourceMapperDecorator.class)
public interface MediaResourceMapper {
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also do this by telling MapStruct which service it needs so it can map the `filename` to the `resourceFile`, `String` to `byte[]`.

Your service API:

```
public interface FileLoader {

    // @Named or some custom annotation annotated with @Qualifier can be
    // used in order to make sure that this will only be applied to the specified mapping
    @Named("fileMapper")
    byte[] loadFile(String filename);
}
```

You Mapper will look like:

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring", uses = {VehicleMapper.class, FileLoader.class })
public interface MediaResourceMapper {

    @Mapping(source = "originalMediaFileName", target = "resoruceFile", qualifiedByName = "fileMapper") // or qualifiedBy = CustomAnnotation.class
    MediaResourceDTO mediaResourceToMediaResourceDTO(MediaResource mediaResource);

   //The rest is the same
}
```

I personally prefer this approach over decorators as you will have only one place where you define your mapping and MapStruct will handle the rest.

More information for the mapping based on qualifiers can be found [here](http://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/reference/html/#selection-based-on-qualifiers) in the reference documentation.